# javascript - finding strings in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

a little twist on the usual "finding string in an array" question:

I currently know how to find a string in an array, using a for loop and if statement.  But what I want to do is return an option if no matching string can be found once iterating through the entire array.  The obvious problem is that if I include an else option in my current if-statement, each iteration that there is no match moves to the else.

So basically, I want to scan through the entire array.. IF there's a match I want to print "abc" and if there is no match at all I want to print "xyz".  How do I do this?  Thanks (super novice here :)).

```
var guestList = [
"MANDY",
"JEMMA",
"DAVE",
"BOB",
"SARAH",
"MIKE",
"SUZY"
];

var guestName = prompt("Hello, welcome to The Club. What is your name?").toUpperCase();

for (var i=0; i<guestList.length; i++){
    if (guestName === guestList[i]){
        alert("Hi " + guestName + " You are on the list! Enjoy The Club");
    }
}
```

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

No for loops required

```js
if(guestList.indexOf(guestName) === -1)
   return "xyz"
else
  return "abc"
```

Comment: `return guestList.indexOf(guestName) === -1 ? "xyz" : "abc";`

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to print the guest name, you can give a default guest name, and than it might be changed or not during the for loop:

```
    var guestName = prompt("Hello, welcome to The Club. What is your name?").toUpperCase();
    var member = "GUEST";
    for (var i=0; i < guestList.length; i++) {
        if (guestName === guestList[i]){
            member = guestName;
            break;
        }
    }
    alert("Hi " + member);
```

Or with jQuery and without a for loop:

```
var member = "GUEST";
if ($.inArray(guestName, guestList) > -1) {
    member = guestName;
}
alert("Hi " + member);
```

See the documentation of jquery inArray:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```js
var guestList = [
  "MANDY",
  "JEMMA",
  "DAVE",
  "BOB",
  "SARAH",
  "MIKE",
  "SUZY"
];

var guestName = prompt("Hello, welcome to The Club. What is your name?").toUpperCase();

var greet = "xyz";//put the default text here
for (var i = 0; i < guestList.length; i++) {
  if (guestName === guestList[i]) {
    greet = "Hi " + guestName + " You are on the list! Enjoy The Club";
    break;//match found, stop loop
  }
}
alert(greet);//greetings here
```